# L'Hôpital's rule to approximate a function

Tags: limits, taylor-expansion, linear-approximation

I came across a simple problem:

*Show $\sqrt{1+x}\approx 1 + \frac{x}{2}$ holds near $0$.*

Interesting to me was the way the author solved this using l'Hôpital's rule:

*Since $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-(1+\frac{x}{2})}{x^2}$ exists and is constant ( by l'Hôpital's rule), we can conclude $\sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+\mathcal{O}(x^2)$.*

This seems intuitive. My question is, how to formally come up with the limit expression? Does this technique generalize?

Comment: Do you know how to compute the Taylor series of a function around $x = 0$?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with Maclaurin series

Comment: I do not think the author intended to **solve**...but I would be hoping to know if such methods do exist. Also, who is the author and what's the book/paper?

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi it seems the OP is asking how to come up with the clever approximation polynomial on the RHS. I am happy for the OP to clarify.

Comment: @gt6989b `My question is, how to formally come up with the limit expression?` this is what got me confused, I thought OP required a way to directly write such limits without using series expansions

Comment: @Anindya Prithvi you're right. I used "solve" loosely here. The problem is from book _A Primer For The Mathematics Of Financial Engineering_ by Stefanica.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the idea is to expand the LHS into Taylor series around the point in question. Here, expanding $f(x) = (1+x)^{1/2}$ to Taylor series, first term is $f(0) = 1$, then
$$
f'(x) = \frac{1}{2} (1+x)^{-1/2},
$$
so $f'(0) = 1/2$. Along the same lines,
$$
f''(x) = \frac{-1}{4} (1+x)^{-3/2},
$$
and $f''(0) = -1/4$. Thus, for a 2 term expansion, you get
$$
f(x) \approx f(0) + xf'(0) = 1+x/2 + O(x^2),
$$
or for a 3-term expansion,
$$
f(x) \approx f(0) + xf'(0) + \frac{x^2}{2!} f''(0) = 1+x/2 - \frac{x^2}{8} + O(x^3).
$$

---

The reason why this works, is if $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^N a_k x^k + O(x^{N+1})$ (where $a_k$ you get from Taylor series), then
$$
\frac{f(x) - \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} a_k x^k}{x^N} = \frac{a_N x^N + O(x^{N+1})}{x^N} = a_N + O(x) \to a_N,
$$
as $x \to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Indipendetly form Taylor's series concept, by little-o and Big-O [notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition) we have that

$$f(x)=o(g(x)) \iff \lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$$

form here, by standard limits, we can obtain the following foundamental expansions

- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x}=0 \implies \sin x =x + o(x)=x + O(x^2)$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\cos x-\left(1-\frac12x^2\right)}{x^2}=0 \implies \cos x =1-\frac12x^2 + o(x^2)=1-\frac12x^2+ O(x^3)$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{\log(1+x)-x}{x}=0 \implies \log(1+x) =x + o(x)=x + O(x^2)$
- $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-(1+x)}{x}=0 \implies e^x =1+x + o(x)=1+x + O(x^2)$
- $\ldots$

therefore in this case we have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-(1+\frac{x}{2})}{x}=0 \implies \sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}+o(x)=1+\frac{x}{2}+O(x^2)$$

and

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\frac{\sqrt{1+x}-(1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac18x^2)}{x^2}=0 \implies \sqrt{1+x}=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac18x^2+o(x^2)=1+\frac{x}{2}-\frac18x^2+O(x^3)$$

Comment: This was the idea I was looking for. However, I don't think this is right. I think we should allow the limit to be a positive constant by definition.

Comment: There was a prior answer similar to this which I accepted. For some reason the prior answer is now deleted.